# How time is measured in gremlin console

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am  trying to understand how is time measured in gremlin console in milliseconds or in seconds. I used method clock() and it gives me result as 0.23456789.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of `clock` is here.
https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/cff4c161615f2b50bda27b6ba523c7f52b833532/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/util/TimeUtil.java

The result is generated using :

```
 public static double clock(final int loops, final Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run(); // warm-up
        return IntStream.range(0, loops).mapToDouble(i -> {
            long t = System.nanoTime();
            runnable.run();
            return (System.nanoTime() - t) * 0.000001;
        }).sum() / loops;
    }
```

So the time taken for each run you asked for using `clock` is calculated using nano seconds and multiplied by 0.000001. The results are summed and divided by the number of runs you asked for to yield the average time. So the result is in milliseconds. I hope that helps.